# How to Post into a third party URL and get access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have a challenge. I have a 3rd party URL as given below:

```
URL: http://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/oauth/login

Request:
{
 "username": to_be_shared,
 "password": to_be_shared
 
}
Response:
‘{
 "response_code": "00",
 "response_description": "Success"
 "data": {...},
 "size": 0,
 "access_token": "access_token",
 "refresh_token": "refresh_token",
 "expires_in": "18000000",
 "token_type": "BEARER"
}’
```

**Sample Access Token Request Call:**

```
url = "http://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/oauth/login"
payload = '{
 "username": to_be_shared,
 "password": to_be_shared
 
}'
headers = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

I am to POST into that given url of the third party and get their response, including the access token.

So far, I have done this:

DTO:

```
public class OAuthLoginRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

}

public class OAuthLoginResponse
{
    public string response_code { get; set; }
    public string response_description { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

So far, this is what I have:

```
public class GenericResponseDto<T>
{
    public string response_code { get; set; }
    public string response_description { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(OAuthLoginRequest request);
}


public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    public async Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(OAuthLoginRequest request)
    {
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<object>();

        return response;
    }
}
```

DIServiceExtension:

```
public static class DIServiceExtension
{   
    public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Service Injections Here -- Auth
        services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();
```

Using HttpClient, How do I complete AuthService and when user enters the required username and password, submits the request then it gets the response including access token from the third party URL (http://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/oauth/login) as response?

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW please use either [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-6.0) or [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm) depending on what serialization/ deserialization library you're using and keep the names of the properties in your C# classes C#-like (i.e PascalCase, not snake_case)
The answer is written assuming you did that, so I'll use the `ResponseCode` property instead of `response_code`

---

Now to the actual answer.

This is relatively simple, you just need to post your data to the third part API, read the result and return it up the call stack. Like so

```cs
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    // Configure your HttpClient injection as described here:
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public AuthService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<OAuthLoginResponse> LoginUser(OAuthLoginRequest request)
    {
        var postContent = new StringContent(
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(request),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"
        );

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("oauth/login", postContent);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("Third party API request failed");

        await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<OAuthLoginResponse>(stream);
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a `OAuthLoginResponse` directly, you could change your `GenericResponseDto` first of to something specific like `OAuthResponseDto` and secondly to have the fields you need, like

```cs
public class OAuthResponseDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("response_code")]
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("response_description")]
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }

    // More properties, like AccessToken, RefreshToken, ExpiresIn...
}
```

And then replace the last two lines of the `LoginUser` with this:

```cs
await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var response = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<OAuthLoginResponse>(stream);

return new OAuthResponseDto
{
    ResponseCode = response.ResponseCode,
    ResponseDescription = response.ResponseDescription,
    // rest of the mapping
};
```

---

Small aside, this is how you'd configure your `HttpClient` injection

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api");
});
```

---

**Note:** I intentionally left out quite a bit of error checking to make this answer short and sweet, but it's still quite a long answer, you'll have to add that error checking in your implementation.

**Note 2:** I also don't 100% guarantee that all of this compiles first go, I did my best, but I wrote a large part of this in the Stack Overflow editor, there may be a missing parenthesis or comma or semicolon somewhere, trivial fixes

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. At what point do I apply AddHttpClient because the response will be sent by the third party when I send the request through that given url?

Comment: You add it where you're adding the rest of the services, so your startup code. And yes, that's how a REST API works

Comment: See the updated code. I have already updated my code with    DIServiceExtension:

    public static class DIServiceExtension
    {   
        public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add Service Injections Here -- Auth
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
        }
    }

Program.cs

    builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

Comment: Secondly, assuming I don't know the response coming from the third party url. How do I write my code for the response?  Thanks

Comment: Before `services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>()` you need to call `services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>(client => ... )`. Secondly, if you don't know the format of the response then you can only *guess* at how to interpret it, but that's a whole other can of worms.

Comment: While I was asking is this: in the response as shown in my question, there is something like:   "data": {...},   and I don't know what it entails. How do I do this?     Secondly, what can I read to understand this concept more. Thanks a lot.